# Power BI calculate sum between two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 4 column master table ([Project], [DTETm], [Allotments], [Expense]) and I'm trying to calculate burn rate between 2 dates. DTETm contains both date and time. Both slicers uses the same DTETm column.

I haven't been able to get the measure to work or return the date.

Thanks in advance.

```
_DurationAllot = 
var DteFrom = SELECTEDVALUE('Master'[DTETm])
var DteTo = SELECTEDVALUE('Date To'[DTETm])
var vResults = CALCULATE(sum(Master[Allotments]),Master[DTETm] >= DteFrom, Master[DTETm])<=DteTo 
Return vResults
```

[image: Burn rate Snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident I found [this YouTube video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=knXFVf2ipro). It walks you through each step of the process and I just tailered it to the dataset I'm using.

Final result:

[image: final result]

Comment: At minimum, the steps to resolve your issue should be provided in the question itself rather than requiring future users to leave the site to find an answer.

Comment: There were too many steps to list. The video made it a lot easier to follow than bunch of steps especially for those who is still learning Power BI, like me. There were tables, slicers, joins and measures that had to be created.  I'll remember that for next time when it doesn't involved lots of steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Calendar table related to your fact table, you can just create a simple measure

```
Total Allotments = SUM(Master[Allotments])
```

and then you add a Date slicer ("between" style) using the Date column from your Date dimension table, then you can just select the two "ends" of the range, and it'll give you the answer you want. No complex DAX required.
Otherwise, you would have to "harvest" the min and max of the selected dates, and apply them in your filter.

```
CALCULATE(
SUM(Master[Allotments]),
FILTER(ALL('DimDate'),[Date]>=MIN('DimDate'[Date]) &&
             [Date]<=MAX('DimDate'[Date])
    ))
```

If you need to create a Date dimension table, you can use CALENDARAUTO() if you have several fact tables, or something like this:

```
CALENDAR(
   MINX('Master',[DteTm]),MAXX('Master',[DteTm])
)
```

you'll get a list of all dates in the range, and you can just use that [date] value in your slicer.

Comment: I probably should have stressed that the time is important factor especially during closeout.  I had thought about between function and calendar table, they ignored the time.

Comment: Yeah, That's complicated. I guess you could create a calendar with a time bucket... how far down did you need to go? Is 15 minutes enough?

Comment: 30min should work and spans at least 7 years.   Isn't there a way to grab the value from the slicer?

Comment: Sorry, grab which value? The start and end date/times of the span?

Comment: need to sum all the Allotments between the start date/time and end date/time.  Then do the same thing with expenses and calculate the %.

Comment: Drats additional requirements.   Calculate the difference between  the two date/time and show non zero value.  (find which projects entering expenses at the last minute)

Comment: Got some data, or can I just make it up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255353/discussion-between-pieter-and-draco).

Comment: Pieter, want to thank you for your time and help. I found this site by accident and it gave me what I was looking for.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knXFVf2ipro